# JSON to JS with Django: SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I'm attempting to get a JSON file into a script. I can't seem to be able to get it there by serving it from the filesystem so I made a view that returns the JSON data to the page like so:

```
def graph(request, d):                  #d.data is the file in the database
    data = json.load(d.data)
    return render(request, 'temp/template.html', {'json': data})
```

In my JS:

```
var j = {{ json|safe }};
```

When I look at the source for the JS it shows the data in this format:

```
{u'people': [{u'name': u'steve'}, {u'name': u'dave'}]}
```

Which I read shouldn't be a problem. I don't have any variables called 'id' and yet I get the error in the title pointing to the provided line of JS.

Why could this be? Also how do I then use the objects from the JSON in my script?

Comment: `u'name'` is invalid in JS. it should be without the u.

Comment: That's because Django returns a unicode array, do you know of any way of either parsing that into valid JS or getting the view to return it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using simplejson:

```
import simplejson as json
```

And everything else as above. This is because the built in json.dumps returns an array of unicode like:

```
{u'people': [{u'name': u'steve'}, {u'name': u'dave'}]}
```

When using simplejson that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Really, no. The output of simplejson is the same as json, your problem was that you did not actually call `json.dumps()`.

Comment: I was having different errors with dumps sadly such as xyz is not serializable